# Passing form data from PDF to a servlet in iText

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, itext

I have a PDF that contains a form that should be filled by users that transfers the submitted data to a database. For example, it contains the name, age, and comments fields. The user fills out this form and hits the "POST" button in the PDF.

The code for the POST button is given:

```
PushbuttonField button1 = new PushbuttonField(
      stamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(90, 660, 140, 690), "post");
button1.setText("PDFPOST");
button1.setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.7f));
button1.setVisibility(PushbuttonField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT);
PdfFormField submit1 = button1.getField();
submit1.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm(
      "http://192.168.1.136:8085/LogFileExampleProject/PdfService", null,
       PdfAction.SUBMIT_PDF));
// add the button
stamper.addAnnotation(submit1, 1);
```

However, when the POST button is pushed after the user has filled out the form in the PDF, it makes a connection with the URI specified in `createSubmitForm`, but doesn't pass any of the `TextField` parameters. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented, the option `SUBMIT_PDF` only works if you have Adobe Acrobat on the client side (this is one of the limitations imposed by Adobe on Adobe Reader). How do you want to receive the data? As an HTML query string (`SUBMIT_HTML_FORMAT`), as FDF (the default), or as XFDF (`SUBMIT_XFDF`)?

Comment: As a HTML query string would be great, but my servlet doesn't seem to receive any data from either `GET` or `POST`.

Comment: That would surprise me. Use this Servlet: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=169 It doesn't do much, it just shows whatever data was sent to the server. Also: which PDF viewer are you using? Surely, you're talking about Adobe Reader and not something like Preview, aren't you?

Comment: I've been trying this on Google Chrome with the PDF viewed in the browser. Should I be trying it with Adobe Reader?